# Proving Legendre's Sum of 3 Squares Theorem via Geometry of Numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, geometry-of-numbers

Every positive integer can be written as the sum of 4 squares $n = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2$ however, if we only allow [sum of 3 squares](http://oeis.org/A000408) some numbers have to be left out:

> $n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$  $\longleftrightarrow$ $n \equiv 4^a (8k+7)$

Excuse me for using the same letter twice to mean different things...

---

I am trying trying to find a proof of this result from within Cassels' [Rational Quadratic Forms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486466701), but it's not always the easiest to read.  In that book **Legendre's Theorem** is stated in a very general way:

> Let $g(x) = \color{lightgry}{a}_1 \,x_1^2 + a_2\, x_2^2 + a_3\, x_3^2$ with $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a_1 a_2 a_3$ is squarefree...
>
> - blah
> - blah
> - blah
>
> Then where are $b_1, b_2, b_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$ not all of them zero with $a_1 \,b_1^2 + a_2\, b_2^2 + a_3\, b_3^2 = 0$

From what I gather, this Legendre theorem is strong form of the [Hasse Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle) and it can be proven using the [geometry of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers) - which is the style I am endorsing today.

By the middle of Chapter 9 - Section 5 to be exact - we get the claim that proof of this theorem is complete.  Because $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$ is the only quadratic form in it's genus.  And that in indeed rested on the Hasse principle.

---

Come to think of it there is a rather serious question here.  Mis-using the Hasse principle slightly we could way:

> The only obstruction to having representation as sum of three squares $n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 $ happens in the 2-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_2$.

How could a statement like this possible be proven geometrically?  Minkowski's geometry of numbers is decidedly a Euclidean result and so the only possible completion that should be useful is $\mathbb{R}$.

In the case of sum of 2-squares the role of the Hasse principle is even more obvious since we can use multiplication identities like:

\begin{eqnarray} (a+bi)(c+id) &=& (ac-bd) + i(ad+bc) \\
(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)&=&  (ac-bd)^2 + (ad+bc)^2 
\end{eqnarray}
and check each time that $n = x_1^2 + x_2^2 \mod p$ and multiply the result.  By Minkowski theorem this only works when $p = 4k+1$.

---

I am going to keep reading, but does anyone know what polyhedron or oval or other geometric shape leads to a proof of the sum of 3 squares theorem?

Comment: Have you seen this recent arXiv preprint? http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02590

Comment: @so-calledfriendDon there must be tons of places I haven't looked but I can't go on forever so I am putting it on here.  Also found this http://math.uga.edu/~pete/geometryofnumbers.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A proof of the three squares theorem by the geometry of numbers was given by Ankeny in 1957. His paper is available [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-02/S0002-9939-1957-0085275-8/S0002-9939-1957-0085275-8.pdf).

**P.S.** Also, I think Legendre's proof was incomplete: he assumed Dirichlet's theorem about primes in arithmetic progressions, which was not known at that time. The first correct proof was given by Gauss. I admit I might be wrong here.

Comment: Wikipedia disagrees: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Legendre's_three-square_theorem

Comment: thanks this is **much** shorter than what I was about to attempt

Comment: @johnmangual, you give a link to a Pete L. Clark writeup in comment above. In that, he discusses a very pretty approach, which is also in Serre's little book: the sum of three squares is one of Pete's ADC forms, named after Aubry and Davenport-Cassels, and means that, if $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ represents an integer with rational values for $x,y,z,$ then it also does so with integral values. Pete and I found all positive forms for which this holds, published an article. Turned out we were confirming (and slightly correcting) an existing list by G. Nebe.

Comment: @IgorRivin: Yes, probably this is why I thought I was wrong here. At any rate, a modern exposition of Legendre's proof would be welcome (I recall Andre Weil wrote about this in his history book, but I am too lazy and busy to check). Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3):

A complete proof seems to be given here: http://www.rsabey.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/maths/sumof3squares.html

Comment: I notice [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) on prime numbers in arithmetic progressions is an input.  So for example there are infinitely many prime numbers among $1,4,7,10,\dots$.  And [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) of [Legendre Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) that $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\left(\frac{q}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}}$ is also an input.